# Solving a system of equations - minimizing f

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, finance

*Completely stumped as to how to solve this problem -_- We'd appreciate any help at all:*

Suppose $f(x, y) = 2x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ and $g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$

Show that minimizing $f$ with a constraint on $g$ yields points that
also can be found by maximizing $g$ with a constraint on $f$. (In mean
variance, you can minimize risk with a constraint on expected return,
or you can maximize expected return with a constraint on risk)

Comment: By “a constraint on $g$,” do you mean $g(x,y)=\text{const.}$? If so, do you know about the Lagrange multiplier method for solving constrained extremum problems like these?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to attack this.

1) To solve the constrained extremum problem using Lagrange multipliers, you would set $\mathrm d(f-\lambda g)=0$, which together with $g=\text{const.}$ gives you three equations in three unknowns. Compare that with what you get when you try to minimize $g$ while $f=\text{const.}$ using the same method.

2) The specific functions that appear in this problem make it equivalent to finding the direction in which the quadratic form $f(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+y^2$ takes on its maximum value. Going in the other direction (i.e., minimize $g$), you’re trying to find the closest point of a level curve of the quadratic form $f$ (which is an ellipse) to the origin, which amounts to determining the ellipse’s minor axis.